# Comparing times from strings in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't get my head around this problem. I'm developing a verification app where a user takes a selfie and then uploads it to my server (node.js express.js formidable.js) via a html form where it goes through a number of tests. One of the screening tests is that the selfie photo must have been taken less than 120 seconds before it is uploaded.

I have the photo created date from the photo's exif metadata. It is in the format "2023:09:03 16:48:55". This is the local time on the device.

I have the uploaded time, set by setting a form field's value to new Date() on submit:

```
<form action="/selfie" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fselfie">
    <input type="file" name="selfie" multiple="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lt" id="lt" value="" />
    <!--ADD FIELDS--> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="document.fselfie.lt.value = new Date();" />
</form>
```

Thee user is using the same device to take the photo and upload it. The field comes back in the format "Sun Sep 03 2023 16:49:12 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)".

How can I calculate the difference in seconds between these two dates?

```
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
}

console.log(exifData.exif.CreateDate);

CreateDate = parseDate(exifData.exif.CreateDate);

console.log(CreateDate);

console.log(fields.lt[0]);

submitDate = new Date(fields.lt[0]);

console.log(submitDate);

age = (submitDate - CreateDate) / (1000 * 60);

console.log(age);

/*
2023:09:03 16:48:55
2023-09-03T16:48:55.000Z
Sun Sep 03 2023 16:49:12 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
2023-09-03T06:49:12.000Z
-599.7166666666667 
*/
```

As you can see, I expect about 17 seconds difference but the calculation is about -600 minutes, because of the 10 hour time zone offset. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use difference between milliseconds from those 2 dates with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: @digitalniweb That doesn't help too much if the two dates are interpreted as different timezones ...

Comment: It gives you 'Milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT' so it is independent from time zones.

Comment: @digitalniweb Yes but if you if you have one date interpreted `16:48 GMT+1000` and the other as `16:48 GMT+0000` the difference will be 10 hours nonetheless

Comment: it gives you always GMT+0 so it is independent. (new Date('Sun Sep 03 2023 16:49:12 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)')).getTime() - (new Date('Sun Sep 03 2023 15:49:12 GMT+0900 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)')).getTime() = 0

Comment: @digitalniweb Yes, if you do it like in your comment, you will get no difference. But that's not what happens in OP's code. OPs code calculates `new Date(... 16:48 GMT+1000") - new Date(... 16:48 GMT+0000")`  and that's obviously 10 hours apart ...

Comment: Yes, converting to milliseconds using getTime() doesn't help. They are still 10 hours  in milliseconds apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not 600 seconds but 600 minutes (ie the 10 hours Australian EST is ahead of UTC/GMT).

It seems your backend is running on a machine that is set to UTC (== GMT) timezone, so your `parseDate(exifData.exif.CreateDate)` interprets `16:48:55` as UTC time instead of the local time of your user, because the EXIF timestamp is missing timezone information. (EXIF doesn't support timezone information)

On the other hand, the string containing the `submitDate` contains timezone information (`GMT+1000`), thus, when parsing this string, this timezone information is considered. Thus your two dates are 10 hours apart.

The correct thing, would probably be, to get the UTC offset from your `submitDate` and substract this offset from your `createDate`.

```
//check if the time string contains an GMT offset
let 
  m = /GMT([+-])(\d{2})(\d{2})/.exec(fields.lt[0]),
  //timezone offset in seconds
  offset = m ? ((+m[2])/100*60 + (+m[3])) * 60: 0,
  //to milliseconds and correct sign 
  factor = m ? m[1] === "-" ? -1000 : 1000
let createDateLocal = new Date(createDate.getTime() - offset * factor);
```

If your backend machine is running in a different timezone, you may need to do further adjustments to those timestamps ...

Or alternatively, you can just remove the timezone information from the string you parse your `submitDate` from. This way, all timestamps will be treated like they are in the same timezone as the backend.

```
let ts = fields.lt[0].split(" GMT")[0];
let submitDate = new Date(ts);
```

This will make the difference check work, but be aware, when you store these timestamps in your database, you will endup with timestamps that do not represent the actual time the photo was taken.

Comment: Yes sorry, 600 minutes, 10 hours the time zone offset.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Though I took the easy way out and just stripped the time zone info from the submit date before passing it into new date on the server. Both times then on the same basis.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I suspect the problem may be solved by using `document.fselfie.lt.value = new Date().toISOString()` (so sending the date as UTC date string to the server, and - server side - create a Date from the ISO string (`new Date([ISO string])`) to compare to the exif date.

Otherwise, maybe an (admittedly somewhat ugly) string manipulation of the returned date will work?

```js
const initial = new Date(`2023/09/03 16:48:55`);
let returnDateString = 
  `Sun Sep 03 2023 16:49:12 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)`;
let next = new Date( returnDateString.replace(/GMT.+$/i, ``) );
let diff = Math.round((next - initial)/1000);

console.log(initial, next, diff);
```

I have created a small, possibly useful [Date library](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler).

[A snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ek83hd?file=script.js) for your problem using that library to play with.

To be more accurate parsing the stringified Date you receive, here's a parser factory (using what we know about the [`Date.toString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring) method)

```js
const noOffset = dateStringWithoutOffsetParserFactory();
const received = 
  `Sun Sep 03 2023 16:49:12 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)`;
console.log(noOffset(received));

function dateStringWithoutOffsetParserFactory() {
  const months = `Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec`.split(`,`);
  return dateStr => {
    const values = dateStr
      .split(/:|\s/)
      .slice(1, 7)
      .map((v, i) => i === 0 ? months.indexOf(v) : +v);
    const orderedValues = [
      +values[2], values[0], +values[1], 
      ...values.slice(3) ];
    return new Date(...orderedValues);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I just did submitDate = new Date(fields.lt[0].substring(0,24)); to discard the time zone information from the upload time. That puts both times on the same basis when passed into new Date() on the server , though I think absolutely they are both wrong, they are right relatively.

Comment: Beware: while some runtimes’ `Date` constructor implementations might handle parsing those formats as an argument, neither are guaranteed to produce a correct result [according to the language spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date).

Comment: @jsejcksn See the added factory method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with two different serialization formats…

You can write functions that serialize/deserialize between native JS `Date`s and the described EXIF format (discarding milliseconds during serialization).

In the client code, upload this exif-formatted date string along with the photo. On the server, extract the EXIF-formatted date string from the photo, and then deserialize both exif-formatted date strings to native JS `Date` instances and compare the absolute difference in seconds:

[Code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&ssl=34&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=18#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOAnAtgQygFTgUQA8ZgAKAE2wFMAuRAEWoEo6BnKVGMAc0QG8AUIkQQE7RAAdM5RAF5EpMHTAh0AIyqomcgHyIAyhy7dFTAHRTyhzKiikATABpEAIgAMLpgG4hiVFSgQVCQAAwASPkooKjNuAIAxEAAbJIBNKhtSJgBfGgjLCmpYgIBZBCgACyzEAGpEAEYcvMFhYQKomLioRmispl9sxHzpQujiqAAJOCDWPtzh8lHO0q4QaNmmJojfNpGO8f0qUTByDf7hbJCfbIEBUEhYBEkbVioiEh6qUi4JNbYjHgsBjUfi+EgKACEpAA9AA9AA65D4ABZcoi+PY0UjMYh0ZiaHisRjsmFoeZ1nYfmtNqDWohKqg4AB3RBgKgs-CoRmoUguACqbMIEiO0RkKAw2E8Pguvn8gWCrPZwN6O0QADlVBoeVSoGZWEkYBAvm5nMjNo5VRr1JpvmBfrr9YavgBWZwAdhpAFoGha6Vatbb7XqDUbSAAOZz1Nzmy2am064NO0j1eqRgDMMb9ce1drWidD9WRkYAbJnWv747mHSGvvU3ZGAJxl7wCG53cDQeBIGCsABqmAN5AAkmBoqgAG4D0iYOifZxqWfMOhqOBwJIZJAtPwBIJIErYCpmTBqWaYcY4GDoL7ab1qc+X6-aAA8DXsbioaeut2O4gkFTgUAEMQwCfHIrhvvYaY0G4DbQWmDTFjQyJhjQzrOi4PgCNC0KIHyryICEbIsp8WQhIgXCIAAntMqAiAaVCjiIcDkFQ85rMgaD0hUVCSEEEhwPhcDAFxPFUIQmDoBI66IFEmDkUglQ8QAjiAVDsF2NACD+UCIKwIBqOgMDdCC8hEcqXwQWmzgRogVkIaaDaRvYLbabp+mGVA7wgSZHESrgQEkKQekGUZnzeIg2G4VJcDSFxPaIAOCC8EyRkVCJkj-oBtyRQA8gp3G6Zo46aJprmToOYE9v2g4jmO5WkL4UioK8XkkX+AEBd50RML6zzNW8wEkcFHmtcwFotlpYhrjESRwCYW7tYBo3RM4kUuJZ0GwW48H1IhyGoehvjDUZy2sRFOHrW4kGbXBCFIbB9T2C4vjlTA5CrThHCqa2LZAA)

```js
function formatToExif(date) {
  const pad = (n) => String(n).padStart(2, "0");
  return `${date.getFullYear()}:${pad(date.getMonth() + 1)}:${
    pad(date.getDate())
  } ${pad(date.getHours())}:${pad(date.getMinutes())}:${
    pad(date.getSeconds())
  }`;
}

function parseExifDate(input) {
  if (!(/^\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/).test(input)) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected format");
  }
  return new Date(
    Number(input.slice(0, 4)),
    Number(input.slice(5, 7)) - 1,
    Number(input.slice(8, 10)),
    Number(input.slice(11, 13)),
    Number(input.slice(14, 16)),
    Number(input.slice(17, 19)),
  );
}

function isValidInterval(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime()) < 120e3;
}

const photoExifDate = "2023:09:03 16:48:55";

// Use `new Date()` in your client code, but for the purpose of the example data in the question:
const submitDate = new Date(2023, 8, 3, 16, 49, 12);
const submitExifDate = formatToExif(submitDate); // Upload this along with the photo

// On the server:
const valid = isValidInterval(
  parseExifDate(photoExifDate),
  parseExifDate(submitExifDate),
);

console.log({
  photoExifDate, // "2023:09:03 16:48:55"
  submitExifDate, // "2023:09:03 16:49:12"
  valid, // true
});
```